# Creating a database connection for each loop through a foreach causes step-through code to jump around

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, foreach, database-connection

I am stripping my code down to the most basic that I can get it to, and still cause the problem.

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    CompanyList allCompanies = GetAllCompanies();

    foreach (Company x in allCompanies)
    {
         List<string> warnings = x.GenerateWarnings();
    }
}

public class Company
{
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    public List<string> GenerateWarnings()
    {
        List<string> warnings = new List<string>();

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring)) //ms access database
        {
            conn.Open();

            //do lots of stuff here, but commented out, still causes a problem
            //basically making some database calls to confirm that an expected
            //value is actually in the table.  List<string> warnings is then
            //populated based on the results of these calls.

            conn.Close();
        }
        return warnings;
    }
}
```

So what is happening is that, let's say the first loop through allCompanies is a Company with CompanyCode 0001.  When I step-through the code, I reach Company's GenerateWarnings() code, as expected.  However, when I reach conn.Open(), my next step through is for Company with CompanyCode 0002 reaching GenerateWarnings().  Then my next step through is CompanyCode 0001 again, reaching conn.Close().  This jumping around between instances of Company goes on for the entire foreach loop of allCompanies.  It's not a consistent pattern, sometimes it will jump around a lot, like maybe one company will Open, and Close, and continue on to the rest of the code, then randomly my next step through will be conn.Close() for some Company that ran conn.Open() like 20 steps ago.

I have not specified any thing fancy like multithreading and async stuff or anything like that, so I'm a little confused as to why this is happening.  I would like...

- A) to understand the reason that this is happening and
- B) to know how to stop it from jumping around

**EDIT**: I found a hint that this might be related to the fact that it's an MS Access database.  When I run the page, the .ldb that's created when an Access file is opened rapidly keeps appearing and disappearing.

**EDIT 2**: This is just really weird to me.  I inserted some quick one-liners throughout the process to log the progress of the forloop to a text file with a timestamp, so I could see what is going on exactly, and when I do that, the text logs each row in sequential order, with no jumping around.  Did adding a log to text function call like inadvertently throttle it or something?  This effectively solves my problem, but I am even more confused now than when I started.

Comment: Well, for a start, your example seems to have issues. You're showing code that sets a list based on a return value, which is calling a `void` method. If you can trim it down to an example which still reproduces the problem it will be easier to get to the bottom of.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just a little typo when trimming it down.  That's fixed, so that GenerateWarnings returns List<string>

Answer (score 1):

Why not just move the using/open/close code up to SomeMethod and pass the conn obj to GenerateWarnings?

It should run a lot faster not having to open/close for each item.

```
SomeMethod()
{
    Using(...) 
    {
        Conn.open...
        Foreach (Company...)
        {
           ...GenerateWarnings(conn)..
        }
        Conn.close...
    }
}

GenerateWarnings(conn)
{
    ...use conn to make db calls...
}
```

(Or refactor however makes sense for your architecture to achieve same result)